# Laminas Framework Routing Issue

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, laminas

I'm currently developing a PHP Laminas Framework application, and I've encountered a routing problem.

Here's the situation: When a user attempts to log in, if their password has expired, they're automatically redirected to the '`/password-reset`' route. After the user successfully updates their password, they should be redirected to the '`/login`' route. However, even though the login form is displayed correctly, the URL remains at '`/password-reset`'.

How can I address and resolve this routing issue?

**codes**

*routes.php*

```
// password reset route    
'password-reset' => [
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'priority' => 9999,
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/password-reset',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => 'Authentication\Controller\Authentication',
                        'action' => 'password-reset'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
// login route
            'login' => [
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'priority' => 9999,
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/login[/:identity]',
                    'scheme' => 'https',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'identity' => '[a-zA-Z0-9@.-]*'
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => 'Authentication\Controller\Authentication',
                        'action' => 'login'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
```

Password expiry check and redirect to password reset page in `loginAction()`

```
if ($passwordExpiryDate['passwordExpiryDate'] && $currentDate >= $passwordExpiryDate['passwordExpiryDate']) {
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('password-reset');
            } else {
                // login
                $learner = $service->login($data['identity'], $data['password']);
            }
```

**passwordResetAction**

```
// get user email
            $userEmail = $post['email'];

            $learnerService = $this->learnerService();
            $userId = $learnerService->getUserIdByEmail($userEmail);

            // validate form
            $data = $form->validate($post);

            // change password and save
            $user = $learnerService->changePassword($userId['userId'], $data);

            // success
            $message['success'] = $this->translate('Password reset successfully. Please return to the login page to continue.');
            if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage($message['success']);
            }
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
```